# loop through python list index

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration

I Have a list, and every time I enter "N" in my program I want the list to print the contents of the next index.

```
categories = ["Produce", "Meat", "Dairy" ,"Misc"]
 ...
elif item == "N":
    for d in categories[:1]:
        d = categories[0]
        d += 1
        print(d)
```

I understand that the above code is trying to add an integer to a string and throwing the error. What I haven't been able to figure out is how to increment the index.

I have looked at a few other posts concerning similar problems but it the solutions aren't clicking for me out of context.

Sample output of what it should look like

```
Add Item to list

Produce
>>Tomatoes
>>Grapes
Meat
>>Hamburger
Dairy
>>
```

Entire program

```
def add_item():
    exit_list = ["F", "Finished"]
    lists = []

    start = input("Would you like to add an item to the list? Y/N")
    print("Add Item to list")
    categories = ["Produce", "Meat", "dairy","snacks/boxed goods", "Cans", "Misc"]

    print(categories[0])
    while start in ('y', 'Y'):
        item = input(">>")
        if item in exit_list:
            break
        elif item == "N":
            for d in categories[:1]:
                i = 0
                i +=1
                d = categories[i]
                print(d)

        elif item:
            lists.append(item)
    else:
        print("ok")
    print(lists)
    return lists

add_item()
```

Comment: Note that indentation is a big deal in python. Be careful. (The `for` loop is incorrect).  And, you should explain what it is you want to do in order for us to suggest the best possible way to do it. If I understood you correctly you don't need a for loop at all, just an index.

Comment: @keyser That was my mistake adding the code here. The code is properly indented in the program.

Comment: @Cs142 You need to explain more about what you are trying to do, we are not able to figure it out simply by your code.

Comment: *every time I enter "N"*.  What exactly do you mean by this? is there an outer loop with an `input` you aren't showing?

Comment: @PaulLo 

The program is a simple shopping list. I am trying to add categories to the program, There will be a list of categories. by default when the program starts the first category will be displayed as category[0] followed by a prompt to enter items.
When I Press a button say "N" i would like the category to change to print the next item in the list, and so on. I added sample output to the original post to clear things up

Comment: @RyanHaining I have added the entire program since my communication sucks today.

Comment: @Cs142 tell us what is output when user enters "N"

Comment: @sailesh The next item in the list should be output. Its only purpose is to move forward in the list

Comment: @Cs142 What is next item, u mean 2nd element in list?

Comment: @sailesh program starts at category[0] is output... User inputs "N".... category[1] is output... User inputs "N". category[2] is output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will keep track of an index and increment it each time it's used:

```
i = 0
categories = ["hey", "1", "2" ,"3"] 
...
elif item == "N":
    print(categories[i])
    i += 1
```

And note that this code will eventually go out of bounds. If you want to wrap around you can do e.g. `% len(categories)` on `i`.

Comment: Thanks. This is easily the most readable solution here. It even looks like using len will allow me to create a nested if statement saying when len == category[5].. do stuff

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_item():
    exit_list = ["F", "Finished"]
    lists = []

    start = input("Would you like to add an item to the list? Y/N")
    print("Add Item to list")
    categories = ["Produce", "Meat", "dairy","snacks/boxed goods", "Cans", "Misc"]

    print(categories[0])
    i=0
    while start in ('y', 'Y'):
        item = input(">>")
        if item in exit_list:
            break
        elif item == "N":
                i +=1
                print(categories[i])

        elif item:
            lists.append(item)
    else:
        print("ok")
    print(lists)
    return lists

add_item()
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it is possible, if not better, to avoid using index in Python. One way in your case would be to use a [generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) on your list. The following code will quit when the user enters `q`, print the next item when the user enters `n`, and do nothing if the input is something else.

```
categories = ["hey", "1", "2" ,"3"]                                             
user_input = None                                                               

# Transform your list into an iterator                                                                
categories = iter(categories)                                                   

# While the user doesn't want to quit                                                                                    
while user_input != "q":             
    # The user's input is transformed to lower case                                           
    user_input = input("What do you want to do ? ").lower()                     
    if user_input == "n":                                                       
        try:                                       
            # We print the next value on the iterator i.e. the next 
            # value in your list                             
            print(next(categories))                                             
        except StopIteration:                                                   
            # Raised when the iterator reached the end i.e. when we
            # have printed all the values in the list
            print("You've printed all the list!")                                  
            break
```

One possible output is:

```
What do you want to do ? hello # Nothing happens here 
What do you want to do ? n
hey
What do you want to do ? n
1
What do you want to do ? n
2
What do you want to do ? n
3
What do you want to do ? n
You've printed all the list!
```

Note that this example is using Python3+